# Is there a FAQ list for Ubuntu?

Tags: wine

I am new to Ubuntu and before I start to ask stupid questions is there a FAQ site because at the moment I have a few problems I can't get my head round and would like to see if the answers are there. before proceeding further At this stage I cannot get wine to launch and I need it to down load some old XP programmes
Thanks.

Comment: https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ  https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu  https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine  (have you heard there's search engines available... I just limited to top four results from official sites, top 4 anyway thankfully; me I'd start with the ubuntu result)

Answer (score 0):

*"Is there a FAQ site?"*

---

AskUbuntu is a **Question** and **Answer** site for the Ubuntu operating system.

Would you like to see a list of **[Frequently Asked Questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions?tab=Frequent)**?

Simply click "**Questions**" and you can sort by frequency under the "more" category.

You can also **Search** on AskUbuntu to find questions about a specific topic.